# $\varphi\mapsto x^\alpha \varphi$ is a continuous endomorphism in Schwartz space

Tags: continuity, locally-convex-spaces, schwartz-space

I'm following some notes on functional analysis where it's shown the result presented on the title.
The proofs in the notes is not clear to me.
Before showing the proof I give some context.

The topology on Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is generated by the family of seminorms defined as follow $$
p_{\alpha,m}:= \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} } (1+|x|^{m})|\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|
$$
with $\alpha,m \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$.
Another family of seminorms which generates the same topology is the following
$$
q_{\alpha,Q}(\varphi):=\sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} } |Q(x)\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|
$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Back to the proof:**
Leiniz’ rule applied to $\partial^\beta(x^\alpha\varphi(x))$ yields an upper bound for $p_{\beta,m}(x^\alpha\varphi)$ in the form of a finite sum with terms $q_{\beta,Q_{m+|\alpha|−l}}\ (0 \leq l \leq \max(|\beta|, m + |\alpha|))$, where $Q_{m+|\alpha|−l}$ is a polynomial function of order at most $m + |\alpha| − l$.

**Doubt on the proof**: I get the aim of the proof i.e. showing that $p_{\beta,m}(x^\alpha\varphi)$ can be bounded by a finite sum with terms $q_{\beta,Q_{m+|\alpha|−l}}$, but I can't understand how he uses the Leiniz’ rule to prove that.

I really appreciate any kind of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#Multivariable_calculus) wasn't completly clear to me :)

$$
\begin{align}
p_{\beta,m}(x^\alpha\varphi)&=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} (1+|x|^m)|\partial^\beta(x^\alpha \varphi(x))|\\
&=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} (1+|x|^m)|\sum_{\gamma:\gamma\leq\beta}|\binom{\beta}{\gamma} (\partial^{\beta-\gamma} x^\alpha)(\partial^\gamma\varphi(x))| & \text{Leibniz rule}\\
&=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{\gamma:\gamma\leq\beta} |Q^\gamma_{m+|\alpha|}(\partial^\gamma\varphi(x))|\\
&\leq\sum_{\gamma:\gamma\leq\beta}\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}  |Q^\gamma_{m+|\alpha|}(\partial^\gamma\varphi(x))|\\
&=\sum_{\gamma:\gamma\leq\beta} q_{\gamma,Q^\gamma_{m+|\alpha|}}(\varphi) \leq C\max_{\gamma:\gamma\leq\beta}q_{\gamma,Q^\gamma_{m+|\alpha|}}(\varphi)
\end{align}
$$
where $C=|\{\gamma: \gamma \leq \beta\}|< \infty$ and $Q^\cdot_{k}$ a polynomial function of order at most $k$.